# Encoding conversion from RSS feed chars

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, rss

I am trying to show a simple text RSS feed from a CodePlex project in a window.
My problem is that the feed text contains a lot of character sequences that looks like:

```
&#58;
&#45;
etc..
```

I know that they represent the punctuation and some special chars, with some kind of encoding, but I do not know how I can convert them back to simple ascii chars... I mean, without a switch/case covering each special char of course.

Thank you !

**Sum-up:** How can I convert `"My name is &#58; Aurelien"` to `"My name is : Aurelien"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see by the question generated by your markup, those are HTML encoded characters.

All you have to do to decode them is use [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) to decode them.

If you're using .NET 4.0, you could also use [`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx) which would allow you to continue to target the Client Profile rather than the full framework.

Comment: Your right ! Thank you. Too bad this class is located in the System.Web namespace and thus forces me to switch from a Client Profile target to a full .NET target.

Comment: @Aurélien - If you're using .NET 4, you can use System.Net.WebUtility which should still let you target Client Profile: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx

Comment: And I'm using it. So I guess there is an answer for everything. Thank you very much, sir !